# Representing the precedence of fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equations $3x = \dfrac{a}{b}$ which i'm solving for x.

How can I represent the fraction such that I can visually determine it.  $x = \dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{3} $ is very similar to $\dfrac{a}{\dfrac{b}{3}}$

Would $x = \dfrac{a}{b} \div 3$ be appropriate. Whats the practice here?

Comment: How about $x=\frac{a}{3b}$?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I"ve aware of the fractions rule. But i'm also showing my working out where I do each step.

Comment: $r \div s = \frac{r}{s}.$  Therefore, $$\frac{a}{b} \div {3} = \frac{\frac{a}{b}}{3} = \frac{a}{3b}.$$

Comment: Another option is $\dfrac{a/b}{3}$. I use this occasionally as I step through an algebraic proof.

Comment: Although $\displaystyle{\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{3}}$ is fairly common notation, I think it is better to use one of the suggestions in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best options are $\displaystyle{x=\frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{3}}$ or $\displaystyle{x=\frac{a/b}{3}}$ or $\displaystyle{x=\frac{a}{3b}}$. The $\div$ sign is seldom used beyond pre-calculus as it can often be ambiguous, but it is acceptable to write $\displaystyle{x=\frac{a}{b}\div 3}$. It is also acceptable to write $\displaystyle{x=\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{3}}$, but make sure that the horizontal line below the $b$ is longer than the horizontal line below the $a$; this will make it less likely to be confused with $\displaystyle{\frac{a}{\frac{b}{3}}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is $$3x = \frac{a}{b}$$ and you have to solve for $x$. To do that, transpose the $3$ to the RHS, getting:
$$x = \frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{3}$$
Then use the rule that $$\frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{c}  =\frac{a}{b}\div c= \frac{a}{b} \times \frac{1}{c} = \frac{a}{bc}$$ so you get the value of $x$ as :
$$\boxed{x = \frac{a}{3b}}$$
where $c=3$

Comment: Hi Algebrology. vuvgaG was asking how to represent $x$ as a fraction, and whether it is acceptable to write $\displaystyle{x=\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{3}}$ because of the potential ambiguity.

Comment: @Joe aah, I thought he asked for the value of $x$. But doesn't my answer resolve the fact that it can be written as $\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{3}$ ?

Comment: I think it is more readable if you write $\displaystyle{\frac{a/b}{3}}$ or $\displaystyle{\frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{3}}$ instead.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for your suggestion, I'll keep that in mind :)